# Registering single letter domain, selling subdomains?

Tags: domains, dns, paypal

I am about to purchase x.yz or a.bc (not those, but same lengths). I want to sell subdomains like rst.x.yz to the public, and would be able to run my own DNS servers for it. Is there a system (iPanel or something, preferably free) that I can do this automatically, where the user purchases a domain and enters the IP to point it to (I am not hosting files) and have it create instantly? I am really trying to avoid the PayPal API as not to spend time re-inventing what could possibly exist already.

Do you think I should just stick with cPanel and let users make their own accounts and be touted a "reseller" ?

Other questions:

1) Should I run my own DNS servers as a backend to this?
2) How much to charge, and for one-time fee, monthly, or yearly?
3) Should I stick with redirects, or actually handle the DNS?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as non-constructive. It asks clear questions and I'm in a similar situation and it would have been nice to see some answers here.